# How to use web services from the singleton class for the different url

Tags: iphone, ios5

iam developing an app, in which i have to call many webservices. So, can we place all web services in a singleton class method. and access those method every were in the class is this possible. please help we out.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a method with parameter 'queryType'. Place all the web services in that method and place a check to call the service on the 'queryType'. 
The checks can be a 'if' or 'switch'. For this you need to work around for the logic.
Hope this helps.